# valgrind, gcc 6.2.0 and "-fsanitize=address"

Tags: gcc, valgrind, address-sanitizer

Recently, when compiling with '-fsanitize=address' I am getting
an execution exception when running an application with valgrind 
namely

"ASan runtime does not come first in initial library list"

I am a little clueless what valgrind actually does. The command
'ldd file.exe' delivers

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7755000)
    libasan.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasan.so.3 (0xb7199000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6fdf000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb6fd8000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb6fcf000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6fb2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb6f5c000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x80092000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6f3e000)
```

Any hints?

Comment: Does it work with `LD_PRELOAD=libasan.so`?

Comment: No, with that I am getting "ERROR: ld.so: object 'libasan.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored."

Comment: What about `LD_PRELOAD=libasan.so.3` (and if that fails, `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasan.so.3`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You won't be able to run sanitized code under Valgrind. Even if you get past the problem with preloading libasan, you'll run into conflicting address space requirements (i.e. upon start Valgrind reserves region of memory which is also required by Asan shadow memory) and this can't be worked around as both addresses are hard-coded in Valgrind and libasan. Similar issues exist for Asan and Tsan or Asan and Msan (i.e. they can't be enabled simultaneously). It's unlikely to be fixed as sanitizers are highly specialized to achieve their impressive performance numbers.

Comment: Yes, removing -fsanitize=address from CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG in my project get Valgrind start correctly. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @korst1k Note that ASan and Valgrind may find distinct sets of errors so it's recommended to run your testsuite under both.